# Unit test for AFNetworking Post request

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I am trying to write unit test for my project which I use AFNetworking in.I use the following operation for my request:

```
- (void)testRegisterRequest{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    XCTAssert(Result,"Register failed!");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     //Failure
}
```

As it is asynchronous it never test my XCTAssert line.
I searched a lot but I couldn't manage to find a tutorial or example for these test cases.Please help me by any tutorial link or hint.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you writing an acceptance test of the server? (Totally valid thing to do.)

Comment: @JonReid I want to make sure my API is work correctly and gives me result, for some requests I test it's success and for some other I check the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things here.

1. You can use [expectations](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW6) for async tests: [Asynchronous Testing With Xcode 6](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/asynchronous-testing-with-xcode-6/)
2. You can use [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) to avoid unneeded network traffic and server load: [Usage Examples](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/wiki/Usage-Examples)

Answer (score 1):

XCTestExpectation is a valid approach. Other testing frameworks offer different ways. For example, we can test a success response using [OCHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest) like this:

```
- (void)testRegisterRequest
{
    __block id response = nil;

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        response = responseObject;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    }];

    assertWithTimeout(5, thatEventually(response), is(notNilValue()));
}
```

You would probably test the response for its attributes, instead of simply testing that it is not a nil value.